# React: Off Click not working after On

Tags: reactjs

```
class Time extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      isButtonOn: true,
      timeNow:  null

    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      isButtonOn: !prev.isButtonOn
    }));
    this.handleOnClick();
    this.handleOffClick();
  }

  handleOnClick() {

      var myTime = setInterval(() => this.setState({timeNow: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}), 1000)
  }
  handleOffClick() {

    clearInterval(myTime);

  }
  render() {
    var button = (this.state.isButtonOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF');
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
           {button}
        </button>{this.state.timeNow}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I basically want to stop the current time and resume it from the time it stopped, I don't know what is wrong, Can someone explain me why is timer not stopping after OFF Click i'm new to react?

Comment: set `myTime` as `this.myTime`. `handleOffClick` doesn't have "magic" access to what you set in `handleOnClick`. I'm surprised that `handleOffClick` doesn't throw an error. I'm looking closer now and so many things are off...

Comment: I tried that @Andrew

Comment: Please edit your question and explain exactly what you are expecting `handleClick` is doing.

Comment: https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

**Issue is with scope**

```
handleOnClick() {
    var myTime = setInterval(() => this.setState({timeNow: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}), 1000)
}

handleOffClick() {
    clearInterval(myTime);
}
```

you have defined myTime inside the `handleOnClick`, that should be outside the function or in the `state`
and you are trying to access that variable in `handleOffClick` function, so it will not clear any timeout.

**Solution :** (as @andrew suggested in the comment)

```
constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.myTime;
}
handleOnClick() {
    this.myTime = setInterval(() => this.setState({timeNow: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}), 1000)
}

handleOffClick() {
    clearInterval(this.myTime);
}
```

Comment: please upvote and accpet the answer , if it was not helpful please let me know.